# Eclipse css formatting

Tags: java, css, eclipse, gwt

I have a problem with formatting css file contains annotation (gwt annotation - @sprite).
When I use combination of keys ctrl+shift+f annotation breaks like this:

```
@
sprite
```

And now it doesn't wokk. how can I set this up to not break annotation?

Comment: I believe this is fixed in last few releases of Eclipse